# Why I don't get the new styled spinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using minSdkVersion="16" and targetSdkVersion="21" but still I get the old model spinner in my app. How do I solve this issue? I need a spinner like this:

[image]

Comment: What theme are you using in your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault
```

This will set the styles according to your device's android version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to change the theme in android manifest? Plus, in android studio layout preview did you changed the Theme or that image is from the phone?

Comment: my theme is android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar